# Определить род

Tags: род, существительные

Прошу пояснить, какого рода слова *счет-фактура*, *плащ-палатка*, *кран-балка* и почему?

Comment: @Игорь 13234, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

При дефисном написании двух существительных на втором месте находится приложение (**это его нормальная позиция)**:  счет-фактура, плащ-палатка, кран-балка. Род же такого сложного слова (словосочетания) задается по определяемому существительному, но не по приложению.

Примечание. В виде исключения приложение может стоять на первом месте, но при этом оно не склоняется: горе-охотник, царь-пушка.

Answer (score 2):

Все эти слова мужского рода - род тут определяется по первому слову. То есть, фактически, это счет, кран и плащ.

Answer (score 2):

Основным, ведущим является счет, поэтому словосочетание - мужского рода, а не женского.

Answer (score 1):

Род определяется по основному слову. Т.е. задаём себе вопрос: "что такое плащ палатка в первую очередь: плащ или палатка?". Разумеется, это палатка, а "плащ" - это некое пояснительное, придаточное слово. Соответственно, "плащ-палатка" женского рода. Далее: счёт-фактура. Основное, ведущее слово здесь "счёт". "Фактура" же является придаточным. Значит, "счёт-фактура" мужского рода.

Comment: А музей-квартира это что – музей или квартира? ))

Comment: Это музей. Здесь-то еще понятно, что музей - это актуальность, а квартира - история.  
А вот когда два слова достаточно однородны и равноправны: кафе-ресторан или диван-кровать - бывает непросто. В последним случае отельные словари даже нормирую колебания в грамматическом роде.   
Но это отдельная тема.

Comment: Уважаемый Третий глаз! Вы простите меня, но у Вас странная логика. Вы утверждаете, что основное, ведущее слово здесь "счёт". "Фактура" же является придаточным. И делаете вывод, что  "счёт-фактура" женского рода. Но ведь слово "счёт" мужского рода? Или я не права?

Comment: @user183861, всё верно. Это описка. Благодарю, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Слова счет-фактура, плащ-палатка, кран-балка - существительные , образованные путём сложения. 
 1) Род сложносоставных слов обычно определяется по слову, выражающему более общее, а в данном случае и главное, понятие. Плащ-палатка (ж.р.) - это палатка в виде плаща; закусочная - автомат (ж.р.) - это, конечно, закусочная, а не автомат; роман - газета (ж.р.) - это "толстая" газета, и романов в ней может быть несколько. Также счёт - фактура (м.р.) - это, в первую очередь, счёт; а кран - балка - это, в первую очередь, кран (м.р.).
 2) Если понятия равноценны или слова одинакового рода, то род определяется по первому слову: генерал - майор (м.р.), инженер - экономист (м.р.) - так как оба слова одинакового рода; кресло-качалка (ср.р.), наряд-задание (м.р.)- определяем род по первому слову - так как слова равноценны по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

> Какого рода слова ***счет-фактура, плащ-палатка, кран-балка***?

.

Род существительных можно определить по форме зависимых от них  слов.

См. примеры употребления слов *счёт-фактура, плащ-палатка, кран-балка.*

.

**СЧЁТ-ФАКТУРА**

*При отгрузке товара (передаче имущественных прав, выполнении работ, оказании услуг) продавец выставляет **обычный** счет-фактуру…*

*На сумму своего вознаграждения посредник выставляет **отдельный** счет-фактуру...*

*…приведен рекомендуемый порядок заполнения **корректировочного** счета-фактуры.*

[***Счет-фактура***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0&all=x)  — **м. р.**

.

**ПЛАЩ-ПАЛАТКА**

*Дед вынес из сторожки зеленую **военную** плащ-палатку...*

*Михаил порылся в шкафу и обнаружил **большую армейскую** плащ-палатку…*

*Снимайте ко всем чертям свою **заколдованную** плащ-палатку!*

[***Плащ-палатка***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%89-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x)  —  **ж. р.**

.

**КРАН-БАЛКА**

*Я своими руками свалил **эту** кран-балку…*

*При обработке крупногабаритных и тяжелых заготовок на рабочем месте токаря или фрезеровщика устанавливают **подвесную** кран-балку с дистанционным вызовом...*

*На носу можно установить **гидравлическую** кран-балку…*

*Послать топор **к правой** кран-балке...*

***Кран-балка***   —   **ж. р.**